# Unable to Sign In into Azure APIM Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Scenario:
The admin requires access to the developer portal for Granting Permissions for Product Subscription by user. This Product is associated with API and must be subscribed to, before sending request to API using Subscription key.

Problem:
The Admin receives a notification in email to approve/decline the User request for product subscription. When the admin clicks on the Link in email for the same he is redirected to the developer portal. However, despite of Logging in with the Azure credentials he is unable to Login and will receive the Following Error.
[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/751Wl.png)
Even after clicking on the Forgot Password and trying to reset it the Admin doesn’t receive an Email to reset the password despite of it showing a message as follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Management admins have to login through Azure portal.

You must click on "here" (it shows "**If you are an Administrator you must sign in here**"):

[image]

It will redirect you to Azure Portal. After you log in with your Azure admin account, click on "Developer portal (legacy)" to access it.

[image]